# A question concerning the representation of an Abel group..

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $A$ be an Abel group and $L$ be an irreducible $KA$-module...

I read in a paper that "Since $K$ is algebraically closed and $A$ is abelian, we have $dim_KL=1$"...

I know that the dimension of the representation of an Abel group is 1.

My question is that why the dimension of the irreducible $KA$-module $L$ depends on the condition that $K$ is a algebraically closed field.

Thanks to every one!!

Comment: Because the statement is not necessarily true without that. Take for example the $2$-dimensional real representation of the group with $3$ elements given by rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $K$ is algebraically closed and $A$ acts on a vector space $V$ by linear operators, one can find a simultaneous eigenvector for the elements of $A$. This, of course, depends on the characteristic polynomials for the elements of $A$ to split (which is where algebraically closed comes in).

To see what fails outside of the algebraically closed setting it is useful to look at a concrete example. Let $C_3=\langle c\mid c^3=1\rangle$ be the cyclic group of order 3. Then, $\mathbb{Q}C_3$ acts on $V=\mathbb{Q}C_3$ by left multiplication (the regular representation). There is a 1-dimensional submodule $X=span\{1+c+c^2\}$. Let $\alpha=1-c$ and $\beta=c-c^2$. Then, the 2-dimensional compliment $Y=span\{\alpha,\beta\}$ of $X$ is also $\mathbb{Q}C_3$-stable since
$$c.\alpha=\beta\;\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;\;c.\beta=-(\alpha+\beta).$$

Assume $Y$ is not irreducible, and argue for a contradiction. By assumption, $Y$ contains a 1-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}C_3$-stable subspace $$Z=span\{a\alpha+b\beta\}=\{\lambda(a\alpha+b\beta)\mid\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
Then, we must have $c.(a\alpha+b\beta)=\mu(a\alpha+b\beta)$ for some $\mu\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mu^3=1$ (since $c^3=1$). This forces $\mu=1$.

However, using the formulas for the action of $c$ on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ above, we have
$$c.(a\alpha+b\beta)=-b\alpha+(a-b)\beta.$$
This means that $a=-b$ and $a-b=b$. Hence $2b=-b$, which implies $b=0$ and $a=0$. This is the contradiction we want.

Note that the problem above is that the only possible eigenvalue for $c$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is $1$. The characteristic polynomial for the action of $c$ on $V$ is $x^3-1$ which has roots $1, \omega:=e^{2\pi i/3}$, and $\omega^2=e^{4\pi i/3}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. If we extend scalars in the example above to $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, then $Y$ does contain two 1-dimensional submodules. One is spanned by $1+\omega c+\omega^2 c^2$ and the other is spanned by $1+\omega^2 c+ \omega c^2$. The point is: the characteristic polynomial splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$.

Comment: If the matrix $AB=BA$ then $A,B$ have a common eigenvector. Then all elements of the abel group $G$ have a common eigenvector $v$. Let $V=\mathbb{C}v$, which is one-dimensional.

Comment: You are using the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, which is what guarantees that $A$ and $B$ have eigenvectors in the first place. I'm not sure I understand your comment as it is essentially the same as the first sentence in my post.